# Emacs: Turn off pretty printing in racket-mode

Tags: emacs, racket, pretty-print

I am running Emacs 24.5.1 on Windows 10 and working through the [SICP](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/).  The MIT editor Edwin doesn't function well, especially on Windows.  Racket appears to be a good alternative.   I have installed both Racket and [racket-mode](https://github.com/greghendershott/racket-mode) and everything seems to run okay.  However, `racket-mode` insists on pretty-printing my results.  How do I get it to print in decimal form?

For example,

```
(require sicp)

(define (square x) (* x x))

(define (average x y)
  (/ (+ x y) 2))

(define (improve guess x)
  (average guess (/ x guess)))

(define (good-enough? guess x)
  (< (abs (- (square guess) x)) 0.001))

(define (sqrt-iter guess x)
  (if (good-enough? guess x)
      guess
      (sqrt-iter (improve guess x)
                 x)))
```

This produces results such as

```
> (sqrt-iter 1 2)
577/408
```

Lots of [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pretty-print.html) comes up when I Google the terms "Racket" and "pretty-print," but I'm having no luck making sense of it.  The Racket documentation seems to control pretty-printing via some variable beginning with 'pretty-print'.  Yet nothing starting with `racket-` or `pretty` within `M-x` comes up.  Maybe the fraction form isn't what Racket considers pretty-printing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start the the iteration with floating point numbers 1.0 and 2.0 rather than exact numbers 1 and 2.

The literal 1 is read as an exact integer whereas 1.0 or 1.  is read as a floating point number.

Now the function / works on both exact an inexact numbers. If fed exact numbers it produces a fraction (which eventually ends up being printed in the repl).

That is you are not seeing the effect of a pretty printer, but the actual result. The algorithm works efficiently only on floating point numbers as input so you can consider adding a call to `exact->inexact` to your function.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually intentional and is part of the Scheme standard (R5RS, R7RS). It is not restricted to Racket but should be the output of any Scheme interpreter/REPL. It has nothing to do with pretty printing. It is mostly considered a good thing since it is giving you the exact number (rational number) rather than a floating point approximation. If you do want the floating point result then do request it by using 1.0 rather than 1 etc.

```
> (/ 1.0 3)
0.3333333333333333
```

Alternatively, you can use the `exact->inexact` function e.g.

```
> (exact->inexact 1/3)
0.3333333333333333
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers explain, it turned out this isn't actually about pretty printing.

However to answer you question literally (if you ever *did* want to disable pretty printing in racket-mode):

The Emacs variable is `racket-pretty-print`.

You can view documentation about it using <kbd>C-h v</kbd>.

To change it you can either:

- Use Emacs' <kbd>M-x customize</kbd> UI.
- Use `(setq racket-pretty-print nil)` in your Emacs init file, for example in a `racket-repl-mode-hook`.